# How to run executable file from cmake in python

Tags: python, c, cmake, terminal, binary

So I have created a executable from **cmake** file name  "COSMO" which is running fine if I run it from Linux command terminal

```
$ cat COSMO
```

I am getting desired output
But if I want to open same file using python I use

```
$ python3 file.py
```

where python3 file contains code

```
import subprocess

def executable_shell():
    x=subprocess.run('cd build && cat COSMO', shell=True, capture_output=True)
    print(x)
executable_shell()
```

to make sure cd command is not interfering I make a python file inside build directory where my cmake file is created.

now in both cases I am getting random gibbrish like when i open the executable from notepad. whereas if i run this file directly the format is fine.

if i use .stdout.decode() it is saying
codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 96: invalid start byte

i have used my subprocess command and it is working fine for commands like ls, cd etc.
so how will run it in python

Comment: `cat COSMO` just prints **content of the file**. It doesn't **run an executable**, as you say.

Comment: NEVERMIND  guys the cmake file made by my collegue was bad